# Converting a function from Visual Basic 6.0 to C# is throwing AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, vb6, access-violation

I'm converting a function from [Visual Basic 6.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic) as:

```
Declare Function RequestOperation Lib "archivedll" (ByVal dth As Long, ByVal searchRequestBuf As String, ByVal buflen As Long, ByVal FieldNum As Long, ByVal OP As Long, ByVal value As String) As Long
```

In C#, I'm declare the function as:

```
[DllImport("archivedll")]
public static extern int RequestOperation(int dth ,StringBuilder searchRequestBuf, int bufferLen, int fieldNum, int op, string value);
```

When call RequestOperation from C#, it throws an exception:

> [System.AccessViolationException] =
>   {"Attempted to read or write protected
>   memory. This is often an indication
>   that other memory is corrupt."}

I have successful in calling many other functions like this, but only this function throws the exception.

Answer (score 3):

This function is clearly not throwing an `AccessViolationException` - instead, it is generating an access violation fault by "attempting to read or write protected memory". .NET is translating that fault into an `AccessViolationException`.

You'll have to go figure out why it is "attempting to read or write protected memory". In particular, did you initialize the `StringBuilder` you are passing to it? Please post the code you use to call this method.

Comment: Yes
I have initialize the StringBuilder with Capicity = 4096

Vb6 code calling
Dim bufSearchRequest As String * 4096
retCode = SearchRequestOperation(hDocumentType, bufSearchRequest, Len(bufSearchRequest), fieldIdx, queryType, stringQuery)

and this is C# calling
StringBuilder searchRequest = new StringBuilder(4096);
retCode = RequestOperation(hDocumentType, searchRequest, searchRequest.Capacity, index, queryType, query);

Comment: As Eran says, the error is clearly happening because you're passing a StringBuilder object into a function that is expecting a string. They are not interchangeable.

Comment: Eran is incorrect. The DLL is returning a string through the searchRequestBuf argument. Therefore StringBuilder has to be used. String can only be used if the DLL does not modify the input string. See for instance here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235282(VS.80).aspx

Comment: @ThaiV Can you clarify why you accepted this answer? Did initialising the StringBuffer solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the `StringBuilder` in the function declaration has something to do with it. You should use just plain `String` instead.

Comment: The StringBuilder parameter type is used for [OutAttribute]

Comment: I don't think it's matter. Nevertheless, you have no reason of using StringBuilder as a parameter as it suppose to **build strings** in an optimized performance and not to pass as data container.

Comment: -1 Eran, you are incorrect. The DLL is returning a string through the searchRequestBuf argument. Therefore StringBuilder has to be used - String cannot be used because .NET strings are immutable. See for instance here on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235282(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Wow, that's really weird... I guess you can only expect this crude implementation from Microsoft. I mean - It's a String Builder, it builds strings... what does it have to do with passing data by ref?!

Comment: The P/Invoke mechanism of .NET marshals data between managed and unmanaged code. It marshals [out] string data into a `StringBuilder` just fine. You should read up on P/Invoke before calling it "crude".

Comment: I know what P/Invoke does. The `StringBuilder` part at P/Invoke - I didn't know and never got to use it. It still looks to me like a crude design to use a class called `StringBuilder` to output string data.

Comment: It's used for `out` parameters where the function itself _writes_ into the string buffer you provide to it. The only .NET class which provides reasonable correspondence for a "mutable string buffer" is `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Indeed, hence - crude design.

Comment: How would you design it to not be crude?

Comment: I would use a different name than `StringBuilder`. I'd use StringBuilder for its intended use - to build strings at an optimum efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

```
/// Return Type: int
///dth: int
///searchRequestBuf: BSTR->OLECHAR*
///buflen: int
///FieldNum: int
///OP: int
///value: BSTR->OLECHAR*
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("<Unknown>", EntryPoint="RequestOperation")]
```

public static extern  int RequestOperation(int dth, [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.BStr)] string searchRequestBuf, int buflen, int FieldNum, int OP, [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.BStr)] string value) ;

Comment: In a VB6 `Declare` statement, a ByVal String is marshalled as a pointer to an ANSI string, not a BSTR. If you want to write it that way, it should be `System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPStr` both times